# How to Grow the Arc On Mouseover in D3.js and HTML

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like the arc to grow on mouseover. My code is:

```
.on("mousemove", function(d) {
d3.select(this)
           .transition()
           .duration(200)
           .attr("d", arcOver);
}

var arcOver = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius + 10);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

[Here's my code on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/jooola/k51jc7x8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of thing, you should remove `.outerRadius(radius - 10)` from the arc and add it like this:

```
.each(function(d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 10; });
```

to your pie, after that you can use `d3.interpolate` on `.attrTween`
to increase the arc size through a transition like this:

```
d3.select(this).transition().duration(200).delay(0).attrTween("d", function(d) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
  return function(t) { d.outerRadius = i(t); return arc(d); };
});
```

Here's a fork of your code: [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GLyA70V4X7xqhg06mgMF?p=preview)

Comment: oh... mainTooltip has disappeared... :(

Comment: @joooo I still see it? can you be more specific?

Comment: yes, you are right. I have to change mouse move and mouse out instead of click and dbclick. I ask both come at the same time mainToolip and increase the arc size. Impossible? @Robert

Comment: ja, genau! (definitely) :D I must see your code now. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and or upvoting the anser as well @joooo

Comment: @joooo I only moved the code to `mousemove` and `mouseout`

Comment: D3 javascript not all running in html div.. Maintoolip doesn't not show in html div. what is a reason? @Robert Andersson

Comment: @joooo Post a new question